# Elastic search parse-exception when json query string is correct

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot

Facing a very strange issue. I have an angular app that makes rest call to spring boot api server which uses Elastic Search REST client to make call to elastic server to get the response.

api server acts as a gateway and attaches auth and passes the request to right index without opening the request body.

When I test from local machine it all works fine. When I deploy to my dev server. out of 10, 2-3 request always fails with either

`org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: GET http://172.16.28.103:9200/customer-9/INSTANCE_DISTRIBUTION_RESPONSE/_search: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
nova_1            | {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"},"status":400}`

or 
`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[value_count] failed to parse field [field]","line":1,"col":287}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[value_count] failed to parse field [field]","line":1,"col":287,"caused_by":{"type":"json_e_o_f_exception","reason":"Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@68bca79f; line: 1, column: 617]"}},"status":400}`

Anyone else faced it? Using elastic search 5.2.0

Sample request

```
{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"CYCLE_INSTANCE_ID":45}}]}},"aggs":{"distribution":{"terms":{"field":"CYCLE_INSTANCE_DISTRIBUTION_DISTRIBUTION"},"aggs":{"weight":{"terms":{"field":"CYCLE_INSTANCE_DISTRIBUTION_WEIGHTAGE"}}}}}}
```

Also, I am using a node based rocky-proxy in the middle. The request I am receiving at spring boot controller is getting messed up like -

```
ze":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"CYCLE_INSTANCE_ID":45}}]}},"aggs":{"distribution":{"terms":{"field":"CYCLE_INSTANCE_DISTRIBUTION_DISTRIBUTION"},"aggs":{"weight":{"terms":{"field":"CYCLE_INSTAN
```

So it is sure that b/w node proxy and spring boot something is messing up the request.

Comment: You need to provide the request you're sending.

Comment: added the request.